# Scale given function so that all coefficients have nice numbers

Tags: functions, polynomials

How can I change the coefficients of a given function so that the associated graph stays roughly the same. Is there any method? For example, consider the following function:
$$
f(x)=-0.07x^4 + 1.42 x^3 - 9.348 x^2 + 22.61x
$$
I would like the new graph to remain similar, like this:
[image]

The Lagrange interpolation could not give me a function, so the coefficients have nice values. What is the general procedure if, for example, I want to have a 4th degree function with exactly 2 zeros, 2 maxima, 1 minima and 2 inflection points?

Comment: What do you mean by _similar_?

Comment: @HappyDay What I mean by this is that the new function also has 2 maximum points, 1 minimum point and 2 inflection points. The graph of the new function should simply have a similar course

Comment: Does $-x^4 + 20 x^3 - 130 x^2 + 300 x $ work for you or is it too symmetric? Obtained by slightly changing the coefficients of the integral of $-4 (x-2)(x-5)(x-8)$, so that the critical points are near yours

Comment: @lhf Thank you very much! It's a bit too symmetric. But $−4(x−2)(x−5)(x−8)$ is a cubic function. What is the general procedure if, for example, I want to have a 4th degree function with exactly 2 zeros, 2 maxima, 1 minima and 2 inflection points?

Comment: To get a quartic, integrate the cubic.

Comment: There's an interesting mathematical question in here: given a set of real numbers, how does one find a multiplier to make them all nearly integers, keeping the results as small as possible?

Comment: @TomKern Thank you!